# MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I must convert some stored procedures from MS Sql Server to MySQL

and in Sql Server I have these two variables:

- `@@ERROR` for a server error and
- `@@IDENTITY` for the last insert id

are there MySql similar global variables?

Answer (score 2):

You may get last insert id by

```
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```